# Make Custom :Path for Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

```
belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

  ## Paperclip with amazone s3
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
    :path => "/notes/:id/:filename"
```

Currently my path /notes/:id/:filename

But I want my path like with attachable because it's polymorphic relationship

and also year wise.

like : /:attachable/:year/:id/:filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

I do this following way

```
  Paperclip.interpolates :attached_to do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.attachable.class.to_s.downcase
  end

  Paperclip.interpolates :year do |attachment, style|
    Time.now.year.to_s.downcase
  end

  ## Paperclip with amazone s3
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
    :path => "/:attached_to/:year/:id/:filename"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `:attachable_type` in your path. This will be a string with the class name of the attachable:

```
:path => '/:attachable_type/:year/:id/:filename'
```